# Compilation errors when using Fleet library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am attempting to use the [Fleet library](https://codedocs.xyz/piantado/Fleet/index.html) for a project. However, when run `make` in any of the project folders (e.g., [this one](https://github.com/piantado/Fleet/tree/master/Models/FormalLanguageTheory-Simple)), I encounter several compilation errors.

Here is an example output of `make` for the Sorting model:

```
g++-10 Main.cpp -o main -O2 -std=c++20 -Wall -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wall -Wshadow -Wextra -Wextra-semi -Wpedantic -Wvla -Wnull-dereference -Wswitch-enum -Wno-unused-parameter -fvar-tracking-assignments -Wduplicated-cond -Wduplicated-branches -Wsuggest-override -march=native -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 -fstack-protector-strong --param max-inline-insns-recursive=100000 -fcoroutines -fno-non-call-exceptions -fwrapv -fexceptions -I../..//src/ -I../..//src/Inference -I../..//src/Hypotheses -I../..//src/VirtualMachine -I../..//src/VirtualMachine/Program/ -I../..//src/Statistics -I../..//src/Grammar -I../..//src/Grammar/Enumeration -I../..//src/Data -I../..//src/Containers -I../..//src/Threads -I../..//src/Dependencies -I../..//src/Inference/MCTS -I../..//src/Inference/MCMC  -I../..//src/Hypotheses/GrammarHypotheses  -I../..//src/Hypotheses/StochasticVariables -lm -pthread  -I  /usr/local/include/eigen3/
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/atomic:41,
                 from ../..//src/strings.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cstring:42,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:283,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:10,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/atomic_base.h:129:3: error: template with C linkage
  129 |   template<typename _Tp>
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/c++config.h:522,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cmath:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/random:38,
                 from ../..//src/Numerics.h:7,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:3,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/string.h:28:1: note: ‘extern "C"’ linkage started here
   28 | __BEGIN_DECLS
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/atomic:41,
                 from ../..//src/strings.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cstring:42,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:283,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:10,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/atomic_base.h:139:3: error: template with C linkage
  139 |   template<typename _IntTp>
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/c++config.h:522,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cmath:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/random:38,
                 from ../..//src/Numerics.h:7,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:3,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/string.h:28:1: note: ‘extern "C"’ linkage started here
   28 | __BEGIN_DECLS
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/atomic:41,
                 from ../..//src/strings.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cstring:42,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:283,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:10,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/atomic_base.h:151:3: error: template with C linkage
  151 |   template<typename _Tp>
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/c++config.h:522,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cmath:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/random:38,
                 from ../..//src/Numerics.h:7,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:3,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/string.h:28:1: note: ‘extern "C"’ linkage started here
   28 | __BEGIN_DECLS
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/atomic:41,
                 from ../..//src/strings.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cstring:42,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:283,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:10,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/atomic_base.h:154:3: error: template with C linkage
  154 |   template<typename _Tp>
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/c++config.h:522,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cmath:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/random:38,
                 from ../..//src/Numerics.h:7,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:3,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/string.h:28:1: note: ‘extern "C"’ linkage started here
   28 | __BEGIN_DECLS
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/atomic:41,
                 from ../..//src/strings.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cstring:42,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:283,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:10,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/atomic_base.h:264:3: error: template with C linkage
  264 |   template<typename _ITp>
      |   ^~~~~~~~

etc.etc.

In file included from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cstring:42,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:283,
                 from ../..//src/Dependencies/EigenLib.h:10,
                 from Main.cpp:3:
../..//src/strings.h:175:8: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘size_t count(const string&, char)’
  175 | size_t count(const std::string& str, const char x) {
      |        ^~~~~
../..//src/strings.h:153:8: note: previous declaration ‘size_t count(const string&, const string&)’
  153 | size_t count(const std::string& str, const std::string& sub) {
      |        ^~~~~
../..//src/strings.h:224:6: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘void check_alphabet(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, const string&)’
  224 | void check_alphabet(std::vector<std::string> t, const std::string& a){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../..//src/strings.h:215:6: note: previous declaration ‘void check_alphabet(const string&, const string&)’
  215 | void check_alphabet(const std::string& s, const std::string& a) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Main.cpp:146:7: error: ‘void MyHypothesis::print(std::string)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  146 |  void print(std::string prefix="#\n") override {
      |       ^~~~~
Main.cpp: In member function ‘void MyHypothesis::print(std::string)’:
Main.cpp:159:10: error: ‘print’ is not a member of ‘MyHypothesis::Super’ {aka ‘StochasticLOTHypothesis<MyHypothesis, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, MyGrammar, (& grammar)>’}
  159 |   Super::print(prefix);
      |          ^~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 1
```

I am running this on a machine with g++-10 installed, as Fleet requires C++20 support. I replaced `g++` with `g++-10` in the Makefile to get the right version, since by default `g++` in my version of Ubuntu refers to v9.

If it helps, here's the output of `g++-10 -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-10
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-10-S4I5Pr/gcc-10-10.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-10-S4I5Pr/gcc-10-10.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.3.0 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04)
```

Any insights or suggestions to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Something is wrong with include paths: system header `/usr/include/string.h:432` includes `../..//src/strings.h:4` from the project - that should not happen. 2. In the project there is [src/Strings.h](https://github.com/piantado/Fleet/blob/master/src/Strings.h) but it is named in uppercase, probably to avoid the issue you see. You should check why you have this file named in lowercase. 3. The project is written in quite uncareful and hacky style: the code itself and the [commit history](https://github.com/piantado/Fleet/commits/master/src/Strings.h) just look to be "it's ok if it works".